# What can be a good source for learning the various proofs of the four-square theorem?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I'd read a proof of the fact that any natural number can be expressed as a sum of four squares in Herstein's book on algebra. The proof involved the so-called 'Hurwitz quarternions'. Recently, however, in my number theory class, my professor said that two other proofs were common-one involving theta functions (Jacobi's method) and the other using modular forms. Can someone please provide a source from which I can have a look at these proofs, especially Jacobi's proof using theta functions? Since I don't know modular forms, the latter proof might be inaccessible to me. Still I'd appreciate a reference. It'd be even better if someone knows of a source where both these proofs are presented.

Comment: refs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem

Comment: See the corresponding [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84897/proofs-of-jacobis-four-square-theorem) for references.

Answer (score 2):

For a very short and very elementary proof see the article [A short proof of Jacobi's formula for the number of representations of an integer as a sum of four squares](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9206203v1.pdf) by Andrews, Ekhod and Zeilberger. It proves in particular, that every integer is indeed a sum of four squares. The proof is inspired by Jacobi's proof, but only uses what is really necessary (in particular, we do need modular forms, and we need only very few things about theta functions). In case you still want to read Jacobi's proof, see the reference [J] in the paper.